# SQL Editor for Microsoft SQL server

Tags: sql-server

I'm looking for an SQL editor which can be used to edit queries in MS SQL Server.

Currently I'm using Oracle SQL developer which I like very much, but that can connect to Oracle databases only.

Now I've got access to an MS SQL server database and need to get data from that. We've tried to use:

- MS Access, which is good in simple queries, but graphical editor doesn't support more complicated ones
- Microsoft SQL server management studio seems to be too complex and couldn't find an easy way to just write queries (at least not comparable to SQL developer)

What editor I can use which gives good graphical editor features and connects to MS SQL server?

Comment: You know that's funny, I'm the other way around. I like SQL Management Studio, and don't really like Oracle SQL developer, I think it's not as intuitive as Studio.

Comment: @Chillie thanks for the hint! So maybe I'm not using SQL management Studio effectively if I find it inferior to SQL Developer

Answer (score 1):

You could try using [Devart's dbForge Studio](https://www.devart.com/dbforge/sql/studio/). It has:

- Code completion — to create whole SQL statement in a few keystrokes.
- SQL formatting — to follow common coding style (standard). T-SQL
  Analyzer to improve quality of your code with configurable rules. SQL
- snippets — to save time storing and reusing repeated code fragments.
- Quick object information — to show hints with info on database
  objects.
- Code navigation — quick jump by F12 to variable declaration,
  object editor, etc.

All the features can be seen [here](https://www.devart.com/dbforge/sql/studio/features.html)

Also a quick note, I am not affiliated with them, beyond being a customer.

Answer (score 1):

I recently started using [DBeaver](http://dbeaver.jkiss.org/) and I like it very much. Some of its features:

- free and open-source
- runs on Windows, Linux, Mac OS X, Solaris (eclipse plugin available)
- supports relational DBs (Oracle, SQL Server, MySQL amongst many others)
- supports NoSQL DBs (MongoDB, Cassandra)
- ER Diagrams
- Query Manager (transaction log with success status, all queries can be reused / snippets, execution statistics)
- auto-completion
- SQL formatting
- many shortcuts
- good [wiki](https://github.com/serge-rider/dbeaver/wiki/SQL-Editor)

The full list of features can be found [here](http://dbeaver.jkiss.org/docs/features/).